# How do i understand Pattern matching like “inDTO is not {CanInBound:true}”

Tags: c#

when i learn Pattern matching,I have some questions.
I can understand the code like `inDTO is {CanInBound:true}` means `inDTO !=null && inDTO.CanInBound==true`but i can not understand the code like `inDTO is not {CanInBound:true}`
when i use unit test,`CanInBound==false` can enter if judgment like：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNm4E.png)

how can i split the expression to make me understand

Comment: It means the opposite, `inDTO == null || !inDTO.CanInBound`

Comment: `is not` is just syntactic sugar for negating the entire `is` expression, so if you understand `a is X` you also understand `a is not X`, as it's just `!(a is X)`.